# Java switch structure not reading '\n'

Tags: java, switch-statement, structure, newline, case

I am writing an lexical analyzer. I have a switch structure, and here is a code snippet of the are where the area occurs.

```
    //whitespace
    case ' ':
    case '\t':
    case '\n':
        consume(); System.out.println("consumed ws");
        break;

    //identifier
    default:
        if (isLetter()) {
            consume();
            state = 8;
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid character: " + look);
        }
        break;
```

The problem is that, while it will correctly consume spaces and tabs, it will not consume newline characters and instead goes to the default.

I have comparisons with '\n' elsewhere, and they work fine. For example, if a line is commented out, this code executes:

```
            case 10:
                while(look != '\n'){
                    consume();
                }
                consume();
                state = 0;
            break;
```

So it seems that it is just an error when it is in the switch structure, not if or while statements. However, if I add something to handle newline in the default case, evaluate (look == '\n') to true, even though I print out look, and it does create a new line in the output.

Comment: I think in windows the newline might actually be \r\n, I'm not sure though.

Comment: with what text does the error actually occure? did you try it with another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using MS Windows? If yes, the end line in Windows is `\r\n`. But in Linux your program should be OK.

You should ignore `\r` character by adding another case for `\r` to do nothing!

Comment: but then the switch should recognize the \n and just ignore the \r.. shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. It would not do it!

Comment: But I will test it and let you know the result :) (wait some minutes!)

Comment: I believe adding another case in the whitespace section with \r worked fine. Thanks. That also explains why my comment until end of line worked.

Comment: @GameDroids: I was checking it. The case will not ignore the `\r` character.

Comment: @user1279914: You should ignore `\r` character. check the edit!

Comment: interesting, thanks for trying it out. So where does it leave us? I would say something like `case '\n': case '\r': ` (with no breaks)

Comment: @GameDroids: why `\n\r`? I think you means `\r\n`! yeap? `\r\n` is not a character! It is a compilation error!

Answer (score 0):

boomz answer is correct. I just had to add a under whitespace where the case is '\r'.

```
    //whitespace
    case ' ':
    case '\t':
    case '\r':
    case '\n':
        consume();
        break;
```

Keep in mind that all consume() does is get another character, so nothing else is done here.

Thanks.